# How to get id and all properties from a vertex in gremlin?

Tags: gremlin, tinkerpop

I am using AWS Neptune with gremlin and I want to get the id of a vertex with all properties of the vertex in one query. How can I do this?

I have tried

```
g.V().hasLabel('file').valueMap(true)
```

but the output is:

```
{ "fileSize": [ "9170" ], "Gremlin.Net.Process.Traversal.T": "f1fce58306f85ca7050503160640d735c9919c8fc85881d65de80bfe31b5ca24", "mimeType": [ "text/html" ] }
```

No label and no id is there. The problem with

```
project('id','label',' fileSize', 'mimeType', 'malwareSource').
    by(id).
    by(label).
    by('fileSize').
    by('mimeType').
    by('malwareSource')
```

is that the propertie malwareSource is sometimes part of a file vertex an sometimes not. So if there is no malwareSource property an exception is thrown.

Answer (score 15):

There are lots of ways, but generally use `valueMap()`:

```
g.V(1).valueMap(true)
```

In TinkerPop 3.4.0+, the output is a bit better controlled with the [addition](http://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/3.4.1/upgrade/#_modulation_of_valuemap) of `by()`:

```
g.V(1).hasLabel("person").valueMap().by(unfold()).with(WithOptions.ids)
```

You could also use `project()` in various ways, but that requires you to know all the keys you wish to grab. Typically, you should [know your keys anyway](http://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/current/recipes/#unspecified-keys-and-labels).

```
g.V(1).
  project('id','label',' fileSize', 'mimeType', 'malwareSource').
    by(id).
    by(label).
    by('fileSize').
    by('mimeType').
    by('malwareSource')
```

If a property value is optional to a vertex then just create an if-then condition in the `by()` modulator:

```
g.V(1).
  project('id','label',' fileSize', 'mimeType', 'malwareSource').
    by(id).
    by(label).
    by('fileSize').
    by('mimeType').
    by(coalesce(values('malwareSource'),constant('N/A'))
```

Comment: But I do not want to delete or remove the properties. I want to get them in the result of the query together with the ID

Comment: whoa - i really misread your question. sorry - updated my answer.

Comment: g.V().hasLabel('file').valueMap(true) returns: { "fileSize": [ "9170" ], "Gremlin.Net.Process.Traversal.T": "f1fce58306f85ca7050503160640d735c9919c8fc85881d65de80bfe31b5ca24", "mimeType": [ "text/html" ] } there is no id and no label

Comment: g.V(1).hasLabel('file').valueMap().by(unfold()).with(WithOptions.ids) throws an syntax error exception in azure and in neptune

Comment: how can I use project if I neet the id, the label and following properties: fileSize, mimeType, malwareSource?

Comment: added an example, but `valueMap(true)` should work fine for Neptune. i will point someone with more neptune knowledge than me at this question in case there is some sort of bug

Comment: I have edit my post and explained why the answers do not fix the problem.

Comment: updated my answer again - basically, `by()` can take an anonymous `Traversal` as an argument so you can add more Gremlin there to account for the optional property key. In this case I used `coalesce()` but you could use `optional()`, `choose()`, etc. as well depending on your needs. i'm really curious about `valueMap()` on Neptune though - interesting that it holds different behavior there. i wasn't aware of that.

Comment: Using valueMap(true) should work fine with Neptune. Here is an example from one of my graphs from the Gremlin Console. `gremlin> g.V('3').valueMap(true)
==>{curDelay=[0], country=[US], code=[AUS], longest=[12250], city=[Austin], lon=[-97.6698989868164], type=[airport], label=airport, elev=[542], icao=[KAUS], id=3, runways=[2], region=[US-TX], lat=[30.1944999694824], desc=[Austin Bergstrom International Airport]}`.   Does it work for you from the Console? Also has the latest maintenance been applied to your Neptune cluster? Just want to verify you and I are using the same level.

Answer (score 5):

Now, you can use `elementMap()`

```
g.V(1).elementMap()
```